# Navigate to a View Controller from a class which is not a View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class name "DatabaseHandler.swift",but it is not a UIViewController.I want to go to a View Controller from my "DatabaseHandler.swift"

How do I do that?

EDIT:
My DatabaseHandler is intialized like this-

```
    class DatabaseHandler: NSObject {
    let sharedInstance = DatabaseHandler()
    var database: FMDatabase? = nil
    class var instance:DatabaseHandler{
        sharedInstance.database = FMDatabase(path: Utils.getPath("DataBaseDemo.sqlite"))
        var path = Utils.getPath("DataBaseDemo.sqlite")
        println("path : \(path)")

        sharedInstance.database!.open()
.
.
.
.
.
.


    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some code how DatabaseHandler is initialized and from which view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a protocol in which you could tell the current view controller to open the next one. 
Write this before `class DatabaseHandler`:

```
protocol DatabaseHandlerDelegate{
    func shouldSwitchToNewView()
}
```

Then in the class declare a variable:

```
var delegate: DatabaseHandlerDelegate?
```

And when you want to switch views go:

```
delegate?.shouldSwitchToNewView()
```

Then, in your view controller, conform to the protocol in the `class` line:

```
class MyVC: UIViewController, DatabaseHandlerDelegate{}
```

And implement the function in your VC:

```
func shouldSwitchToNewView(){
// Switch here!
}
```

Then, all that's left to do is set you as the delegate in `viewDidLoad()` like this:

```
let handler = DatabaseHandler()

override func viewDidLoad(animated: a){
    super.viewDidLoad(animated: a)
    handler.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: what exactly should I do in func shouldSwitchToNewView ( ) ?

Comment: If you are using storyboards, you can make a segue to that view by right clicking & dragging from the round yellow icon on the first view to anywhere in the new view. Click on the arrow that appears and give the segue an ID. Then, in the code of the First VC, you can call  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SEGUE ID HERE") (put that in shouldSwitchToNewView()) and it will transition to the new view.